# *ngFor without wrapping inside ng-content

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I need to repeat a component inside another component, let's say:

Component A only accepts, inside its ng-content, a component of type B.

doing something like:

```
<component-a>
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="items">
        <component-B></component-B>
    </ng-template>
</component-a>
```

or this:

```
<component-a>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <component-B></component-B>
    </ng-container>
</component-a>
```

does not work...

I can't modify component-a nor compoenent-B and these approaches doesn't render the component-B...

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Thanks.

PS: I may need to add multiple component-B for each item.

Comment: Don't you mean `ng-container` not `ng-template`? I wrote up the difference, as I kept getting it wrong: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/May/20/angular-ng-elements.html

Comment: pass the array as parameter to inner component, repeat it in the template of the inner component.

Comment: question edited. I can't modify component-b.

Comment: you need to  replace `ng-template` with `ng-container`.

Comment: @Blauhirn As I stated in the question, I already tried with ng-container too. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @SergioFigueiredo I am really sorry, should have read the entire question. What do you mean by "can't modify"? - your code looks fine to me. The only reason I can see is `items` being empty (I guess your  console doesn't give any errors either?)

Comment: @Blauhirn I'm using an external framework, and both component-a and component-b are not mine, if I use something like the example from Jason below it works, but with ng-container or ng-template it does not... no errors, but does not render the items either

Comment: so `component-a` template somewhere has a `<ng-content select="component-b"></ng-content>` inside. One would expect `ng-container` not to affect the requirement. This looks either like bad design or an actual bug by the Angular framework to me. Maybe you could set up a plunker and open an issue on their github page. Good luck

Comment: unfortunately, the entire functionality is [still not documented](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17983).

Comment: I have created a plunker demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/7jlcpU0Wxxo6YxtrY66l?p=preview you can see the intended result on app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I would normally expect something as simple as the below to work:

```
<component-a>
    <component-B *ngFor="let item of items">
    </component-B>  
</component-a>
```

Or with the ngForOf syntax, doesn't really matter. Is there any more info you could give in order to better pinpoint where the issue might be?

Comment: that works, but I can't do that because I may need to add multiple <component-b> for for the same item.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! by using

```
ngProjectAs="selector"
```

attribute on ng-container!